# best practice to use action url while calling ajax in cakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, url-rewriting

I am using ajax with jQuery in my cakePHP application.
and my javascript function is placed inside a javascript file.

now in my local system the files are kept in "/sample" directory so the the path while i call the function will be

in ajax.js

```
$.post({url : "/sample/controller/action"})
```

but after hosting it the url will become

```
$.post({url : "/mydomain.com/controller/action"})
```

in cakePHP we `$html->url` to generate urls
but since this code is in js file i can't use that function

**i don't want to change the all ajax action urls manually before hosting**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What to do is in your master template for your cake app create a **global** javascript variable that can be used throughout your application. Make sure it exists befor you do any JS includes too.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">var myBaseUrl = '<?php echo $html->url; ?>';</script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mycustomJSfile.js">
    ...
</head>
```

Now you can do things like this from any view file you have in your MVC framework app.

```
$.post({url: myBaseUrl + 'controller/action'});
```

Comment: I do this for every web application i write using any framework. It's even more handy if you're using Smarty and need the baseUrl in javascript. You'd have to do {/literal}{$baseUrl}{/literal} which is a royal PITA. The above solution solves this nicely.

Comment: This is the correct answer but it didn't work for me. It may be because I'm using Cake 2 and this solution was for an earlier version, though. Nonetheless, the code I had to use to get it to work in Cake2 was `<script type="text/javascript">var myBaseUrl = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/'); ?>';</script>`

Comment: And for CakePHP 3, I used `var appBaseUrl = '<?php echo $this->Url->build('/', true); ?>';`

Comment: How do I pass parameters to the controller function?

Answer (score 6):

I'm updating Paul Dragoonis's answer to reflect the latest CakePHP version (2.2).

In your layout file, set the JavaScript variable with CakePHP's JSHelper: `<?php echo $this->Js->set('url', $this->request->base); ?>`, where `$this->request` is an instance of CakeRequest and gives information on the current request.

After the line above, write the buffer with `<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>`.

Then, you can access this variable in JavaScript with `app.url`.

Answer (score 3):

@irtiza your answer is appreciated but for cakephp latest version 3.x this will work otherwise you will get routing error.

```
ulr:'<?php echo \Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 
'controllername', 'action' => 'actionname')); ?>'
```

Answer (score 1):

in reply to Paul Dragoonis you can use `$this->webroot` if you use subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'all'));
```

Will output;

```
/Users/all
```

in js

```
$.post({url : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'all')); ?>"})
```