# Avoid the display of default layout in AJAX request in CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to show a test div when the event `onchange` of a select is triggered, but in result div total default layout is displayed. I just want `test.ctp` to appear in my result div.

This is my code, please tell what is wrong here. I've a dropdown with `id="ProductCategoryId"` and a result `div` like:

```
<div id="result">result html</div>
```

This is the jQuery function:

```
$("#ProductCategoryId").change(
  function() {
    var catid = $(this).val();
    $.post('product/test', {id: catid},
    function(result) {
      $('#result').html(result);
    });
  }
);
```

In my `product_controller`:

```
function test() {
  $this->autorender = false;
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

and in `test.ctp` only test output is written.

Comment: Can you show us the whole code of the `test` method? Or is it just what you have put here?

Comment: yes, i've to write the code, its just the start, so this is basic code.in test.ctp just<div>output is here</div> writtern

Comment: Have you included the `RequestHandler` component?

Comment: yes, i hv included RequestHandler component

Comment: Try testing the network activity using the browser developer tools (e.g. Firebug) to confirm you are making an AJAX request instead of a regular request

Comment: firebug  shows its a XMLHttpRequest request.
I've used ajax so many times earlier also, but did not face this type of problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5454/discussion-between-elitalon-and-vibha)

Comment: The problem was with the link:

url should be /myapplicationname/controller/function

and function should be
    function test(){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->layout = "ajax";
      $this->render('test');
    }

*referred this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623738/cakephp-controller-response-for-ajax-request-is-wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you have figured out the problem or not. Well if don't want to wrap layout around your view you can simply set layout to false. And I see you have disabled the auto rendering that means you are specifically calling controller's `render('test')` function.??

```
   $this->autorender = false;
   $this->layout = false;
   $this->render('test');
```

Comment: The problem is solved, it was with the link:

url should be /myapplicationname/controller/function

and function should be
    function test(){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->layout = "ajax";
      $this->render('test');
    }

*referred this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623738/cakephp-controller-response-for-ajax-request-is-wrong

Comment: For others that find this, be aware that it's: $this->autoRender = false; (with a capital R).