# Relative paths for javascript on CakePHP2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I was wondering if there's any way to do something similar to what `HtmlHelper` does in Cake views: instead of having to write the URL manually, calling some kind of helper to make it for you.

I have taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352350/best-practice-to-use-action-url-while-calling-ajax-in-cakephp) but it is from 2010 and maybe there's something new now...

Currently I have codes like this at my javascript files:

```
window.location.href = 'http://' + document.domain +'/cakephp/posts/view/'+$(this).attr('data-id');
```

But if i change the cakephp folder name, or I use another configuration on the server or something similar, the URL changes and I should change manually all the codes with this type of URL.

I wonder if there's something similar to:

```
echo $this->Html->link('controller' => 'users' , 'action' => 'login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to inline or external JavaScript? Inline is rather easy using the `url` method, which accepts the same arguments as `link` (an array or string containing the URL).

Using it in external files is a bit trickier. I define a JS variable containing the site path before loading the JS files.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var SITE_URL = "http://www.example.com/cakeapp/";
//]]>
</script>
```

In my external JavaScript files I can then reference `SITE_URL` when I need it. When you change domains or rename the `cakeapp` directory you only have to alter the `SITE_URL` variable.

Comment: Im talking about external js files. Your solution is quite similar to the one given in the link i posted, i was wonderting if there's anything better to work with inside the JS files.

Comment: Ah you're right, my solution is identical to the one in the post you referred to. I don't know of any other method, but the above is still being used in recent versions of Wordpress for setting up AJAX calls for example.